# Flexible solar cell powered LED

Tags: led, solar-cell, flexible

I want to make flexible solar cell-powered LED. The flexible solar cell that I want to use is [ONP1.2-12X24](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1009/Electronic_Component_Spec_Sheet_Cla_77DEA84523C82-1658524.pdf) and I just want to use chip LED.

When I connect only one ONP1.2-12X24, it shows near 1.2V. When I connect three ONP1.2-12X24, it shows near 4V by a multimeter.

However, the chip or normal LED does not show any lighting when I connect the solar cell. Where should I begin, or what I should do to use both materials?

I am really a beginner with this kind of project. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have the polarity correct? What color LED? Are you in direct sunlight? Sunlight has orders of magnitude more intensity.

Comment: what is the purpose of the project?

Comment: What expectation of LED current did you have? Did you measure the max output current of the group of cells? Just to get you started: Place a cap of maybe 100uF across the series connected cells (observe correct polarity).  Connect a resistor of about 390 ohm  in series with the LED. Place the cells in a strong light, let the cap charge for several seconds. Temporarily connect the LED/resistor circuit across the cap. If you have the polarity correct you should get a flash or so from the LED.  Now expand your design from this.

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: What is your light source. BRIGHT interior lighting is under 1% of full midday sunlight. Typical interior lighting even less. A PV panel that produced say 10 mA in full sunligt may produce a few tens of uA under typical interior lighting. || Set a multimeter to mA range. Connect meteracross the cells in series. Change to uA if reading very low. What current do you get?